# How Select Only One Record in MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I am doing Win-form project with MySQL.

In My Problem is,.. I want to Show very first data in My Project.

I know if the primary key is standard like 1 means its very easy. But in my project that primary key id is changeable one. If ascending or descending is also take all the record and then finely give the result.

I want very first record na?. Is any to Identify the First record Query in MySQL.

**My Code -**

```
 connection.Open();
                command.CommandText = "select student_code from attendance_master where subject_code='" + subcode + "' and period_code='" + percode + "' and date='" + date + "'";
                Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (Reader.Read())
                {
                    stdcode = Reader[0].ToString();
                }
                connection.Close();
```

Or other wise can i find the min value of primary id value and select the particular record. I don't the this is a best way. But it reduce unwanted execution of records.

Pls give me an IDEA....

Comment: Please read about SQL injection.

Comment: I also think you should read about sql injection and about ado.net command parameters http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson06.aspx

Comment: Is this Question is not Use Full or Clear?. Please Inform That to me. Or My Code standard is very low?. Why this question getting Minus Votes?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the limit statement, Example:

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 0, 1
```

Comment: The first number is the offset to start at, for example if he wished to grab the second result, he'd do 'LIMIT 1,1'

Comment: As I lack privileges to post comments on other users' answers, I felt it necessary to post here: "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table" is an SQL-only statement, MySQL does not support this feature, and is in favor of the 'LIMIT' statement.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table
```

Comment: I try with "select TOP 1 subject_code,period_code,date from attendance_master" this query. But It throw an error "1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 subject_code,period_code,date from attendance_master' at line 1"

Comment: thanks lelewin. Please read Dessix Machina Answer. Its a SQL query. But it not working in MySQL. Thanks for Support.

Comment: yes, it is my fault . I miss that you use MySQL. sorry for this.

Comment: Oh Don't Worry About this. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

you could do this

```
 connection.Open();
 command.CommandText = "select student_code from attendance_master where subject_code='" + subcode + "' and period_code='" + percode + "' and date='" + date + "'";
 Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
 if (Reader.Read())
  {
   stdcode = Reader[0].ToString();
  }
 connection.Close();
```

The way you use SQL is wide open for SQL injection which is a big security problem!
Better use Parameters in your SQL...

Comment: I'd recommend using a parameterized query, to protect against SQL Injection. Especially if sub_code et al are user-supplied inputs.

Comment: big security problem means what?. How it affect the project?. What are the benefit when i go for Parameters.

Comment: Besides using parameterized queries, as recommend by other people, i do also recommend to close `ExecuteReader()` after using it. It prevents the database from locking on the next query. Just had the same problem and thought it was worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

You must sort rows by primary key: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sorting-rows.html
And, then, limit output by `LIMIT` clause: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Comment: I am Aware of Sorting. But it doesn't want when i need only one Row. Is it Correct?. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql
 SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 0, 1

IN SQL
 SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table